# JQuery Slider Code doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Here is the file link:
http://www.webeetech.com/Projects/Test/slider.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">;
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">;    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Slider</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
            setInterval(function() {
                $('#slideshow > div:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
            }, 3000);
        </script>
        <style>
            #slideshow {
                margin: 50px auto;
                position: relative;
                width: 240px;
                height: 240px;
                padding: 10px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            }
            #slideshow > div {
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                left: 10px;
                right: 10px;
                bottom: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
```

Can anyone help??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll wait for your code ;)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Slider</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

Comment: nooooooo... Edit your question and put the code there!

Comment: Put your code in the question itself. not on comments

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);

</script>

Comment: <style>
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}

</style>
</head>

Comment: @user3398595 I've added your code to the question. Next time you ask a question on StackOverflow put your code in the question **not** in the comments.

Comment: Thanks@Anton, But tried. I have to know the rules to put code to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you cannot load jQuery properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
```

result in this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

as well as:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

So correct your path or better using CDN with later version since `1.2.6` is too outdated already:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You also need to wrap your jQuery code inside DOM ready handler:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
});
</script>
```